# How can I ensure that my Jumbotron doesn't resize after loading new content that is smaller/larger?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on earning the Front End Development certificate on FreeCodeCamp, and I am trying to improve some of my older projects. I created a random quote generator that pulls a quote from an API.

When the quotes are populated, the length of the quote can vary, so from time to time the Jumbotron that contains the quote/author will resize to account for that. I don't like this, as it looks jumpy to me when it does happen. My goal, ultimately, is to make sure that the box stays the same size no matter what quote is populated, even before one has loaded.

Would it be possible to set a minimum size for it that is slightly larger than any of the quotes will be (maximum quote length is 136 characters)?

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id='jumbo' class='jumbotron' style='min-height: px'>
    <h1>Quote Machine</h1>
    <hr></hr>
    <p id="quote"></p>
    <p id="author"></p>
<button id='icon' class="btn btn-custom btn-block">I'll Have Another!</body>
</div>
```

CSS (that applies to this situation):

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

[Link for reference](http://codepen.io/hvdrew/pen/wowyYW?editors=0100)

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't abuse the code markup simply to circumvent the restriction that each question must come with accompanying code when an external link to a code dump is supplied. It is there for a reason—questions like this show little effort in constructing a minimal, concrete and verifiable example, and the community will conversely invest little effort in helping.

Comment: @Terry Sorry about that, I'm a bit new here and didn't quite understand the functionality of the code block, and to be completely honest I was planning on coming back and fixing it later when I had more time. I didn't expect this to be seen so quickly! Should be fixed now.